# How do I connect a garbage disposal into a single hot outlet?

Tags: dishwasher, garbage-disposal

We just moved into our new house. When putting in the new dishwasher I found that the old dishwasher was hardwired into the BLACK WHITE BARE black shielded wire going directly to the breaker box. The garbage disposal located under the sink was hard wired to a switch. Neither wire was hot.

I called an electrician who was able to figure out and connect the dishwasher to the breakerbox that provided an outlet. But how do I now go about connecting and getting power to that disposal with only the single hot outlet to connect both?

Comment: Could you clarify this a little, with more specific details? It's kind of hard to tell what you're saying is connected to which, and where. It isn't unusual for a dishwasher to be hard-wired. The disposal obviously needs to be switched, and you could just connect your switch loop directly into the hot wire in the same junction box (presumably under the cabinet) that your dishwasher is wired into, if it isn't already.

Comment: Photos of the outlet in question would be helpful.